# iOS APNS via AWS SNS odd rate of failure

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

I have an application in which I am sending push notifications to iOS devices using AWS SNS. My application reports that 100% of the notifications are being successfully added AWS SNS. However, when I look at my cloud watch metrics in the AWS dashboard, a number of messages aren't being delivered, there is no discernible pattern.

I have done testing by sending requests to my server via curl, the server reports back success, I then can watch the notification come in to my iPhone. If I send 4 - 6 requests in a row, over the span of about 10 seconds, only about 3 messages actually get delivered. If I wait for a couple of seconds after the failures, then I can repeat this same behavior.

I have also observed a strange behavior where notifications will not be delivered, but periodically, it seems that a single message will force through all of the undelivered messages and I'll get a flood of notifications.

What in the world is going on here, is this an AWS problem? Have other people been experiencing this with SNS?

**Update June 18, 2014**

I am working on another project now using NodeJS, so I am using the JavaScript AWS SDK. This post originally was about a project using the PHP AWS SDK. I haven't really seen the behavior described above while using the JavaScript AWS SDK.

Comment: I have seen the exact same behavior but have no idea why.  Even when the SNS API reports publish succeeded and gives me a messageId it's still not reliable that it will actually show up on the device.

Comment: Exactly, what's more. I have noticed that when SNS reports undelivered messages, that those messages have actually come through to the device, leaving me with even less information to work with.

Comment: Are you in the sandbox or are you testing through the live APNS servers?  I have found more reliability with the live servers.  Also if you are back and forth between a dev environment and a prod one I've noticed that SNS will disable the endpoint associated with my dev device (probably due to too many failures or something) - I have to re-enable it manually.

Comment: Live servers, I have also noticed the disabling of endpoints as you have noticed as well

Comment: I am experiencing the same. Just migrated a 9,000 users to figure out that aws sns push works ok with small volumes but when I publish to a topic with more than 5,000 it is unreliable. I can even go back and send a direct message to a device that didn't received the push and they will get it as a direct message but not as part of the topic.

Comment: Hi, did you find anything regarding to your question? tnx

Comment: No, but I am working on a new project and using APNS via AWS and haven't noticed this behavior as much. The difference with this project is that I am using NodeJS, so I'm using the NodeJS AWS SDK, the project that I reported this on was using PHP and the PHP AWS SDK, so maybe there is some difference there.